# Using a select box to swap classes between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 divs, each containing a select box that lists all the divs.
I am trying to make it so that when you use the select box it swaps the class of the div you are using to the the div you selected.

I have set the classes to change the column position using css flex.

So far it will work correctly on the first change but not on any after that.
What am I doing wrong here?

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wd9vrfmn/

JQ:

```
  var col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'] //List of classes

  $("select").change(function(){
    var prevClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var nextClass = col[$(this).val() - 1];
    $(this).val($(this).find('option[selected]').val());
    $('div.' + prevClass).removeClass(prevClass).addClass("col0");
    $('div.' + nextClass).removeClass(nextClass).addClass(prevClass);
    $('div.col0').removeClass("col0").addClass(nextClass);
  });
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine on chrome

Comment: If you try changing one, then changing it back to what it was, you should see the problem. I see the same problem in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of options is not getting updated. I have added following code:

```
var prevId = $(this).parent().attr('class').replace("col","");
var nextId = $(this).val();
var prevElem = $("option[value="+prevId+"]");
var nextElem = $("option[value="+nextId+"]");
$(prevElem).val(nextId);
$(nextElem).val(prevId);
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/wd9vrfmn/2/).

Comment: This made me realize my error, but the solution is simpler than that, just needed to fix the var nextClass: https://jsfiddle.net/wd9vrfmn/3/

Comment: Yes I agree there won't be any need to change `value` only if you are not using it for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

first add class and then remove class from div Please check.

```
  var col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

  $("select").change(function(){
    var prevClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var nextClass = col[$(this).val() - 1];
    $(this).val($(this).find('option[selected]').val());
    $('div.' + prevClass).addClass("col0").removeClass(prevClass);
    $('div.' + nextClass).addClass(prevClass).removeClass(nextClass);
    $('div.col0').addClass(nextClass).removeClass("col0");
  });
```